# How to Add the value from combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Is there any other way to sum all the items on the combo box

I'm trying to sum all the value on the combo box

this is my code:

```
For a As Integer = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim b As Integer
    b = ComboBox1.Items(a)
    MetroLabel12.Text = ComboBox1.Items.Count(0) + b
Next b
```

Comment: Turn on option strict. `b = ComboBox1.Items(a)` is converting Object to integer.  they are not the same thing

Comment: There is not Count(x) method for the ComboBox items collection. This code is not compilable.

Comment: Are you use a WinForms combobox or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will take the string value of each item and try to convert it to integer.  If successful, it will add the result to `result`.

```
Dim result as Integer = 0
Dim num as Integer = 0

For Each s As String In ComboBox1.Items
    num = 0
    If Integer.TryParse(s, num) Then
        result = result + num;
    End If
Next s
```